# data access from .phtml in to model

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento extension development.

please suggest me how to access the .phtml form data in model.

for ex.in edit .phtml form i have to access the data in abstract.php and make some task on that data and modified data transfer back to in edit.phtml.

Answer (score 1):

`Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();`  this code returns all post variables from form.

Go through below tutorial for module creation.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table